# Tabbing a Calendar console application using C

Tags: c, console-application

I am implementing a simple yearly calendar in traditional format in a console application using ANSI C. The calendar must be tabbed to show in the format of  3 x 4 months. Till now I managed to display all the months beneath each other as shown in the code below. Any help how can I tackled the tabbing part? I tried to split the month[] into 3 according to the column for example Jan, April, July and October will be the 1st column and then work column by column, but I don't know if it is the best thing to do...any help please?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int d,y,no_lp,n,i=1,j,month[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

 printf("Enter year:");
 scanf("%d", &y);

 if (y%4==0)
 {month[2]=29;}

 no_lp= (27 + (42/5) + (y-1) + ((y-1)/4) - ((y-1)/100) + ((y-1)/400) + 1);
 d= no_lp%7;

 n=d;

 for(j=1;j<=12;j++)    
 {
  printf("\n\n       %s",monthname[j]);
  //printf ("\n\n%d",j);
  printf("\n Su Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa\n");

  while(d--!=0)
    printf("    ");  //spaces for empty days

  while(i<=month[j])
  {
   if(i<10)
   {printf(" %d  ",i++);} //formating for dates with 2 digits

   else{printf("%d  ",i++);}//formatting for dates with 1 digit
   n++;

   if(n==7)        //if 7 is reached start new line
   {
    n=0;
    printf("\n");
   }
  }

  d=n;
  i=1;            //n will be the 1st day of next month
 }

 return(0);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/cal-win32/source/browse/trunk/src/cal.c) of the UNIX `cal` command.

Comment: Can you use external libraries? nCurses might be useful for you.

Comment: I cannot use external libraries which are not ANSI C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace

```
   if(i<10)
   {printf(" %d  ",i++);} //formating for dates with 2 digits

   else{printf("%d  ",i++);}//formatting for dates with 1 digit
```

with

```
printf("%2d  ",i++);
```

In order to print 3 * 4, don't print on the fly

Store those values

```
char out[12][6][24];
          |  |  |
n months <-  |  -> string containing week in calendar (e.g 10 11 12 13 14 15 17)
             V
    Max weeks in a month
```

and print

```
week 1 month 1 , week 1 month 2 ,  week 1 month 3
week 2 month 1 , week 2 month 2 ,  week 2 month 3
week 3 month 1 , week 3 month 2 ,  week 3 month 3
...
week 1 month 4 , week 1 month 5 ,  week 1 month 6
week 2 month 4 , week 2 month 5 ,  week 2 month 6
week 3 month 4 , week 3 month 5 ,  week 3 month 6
...

...
```